# Display related items of another list in DispForm.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm kind of new to Sharepoint 2013 and I'm given with a requirement to develop a Task management solution. I developed up to some extent but I'm stuck at this bit.

I have two lists and a document library as follows.

Tasks : **task_id**, description, etc

Discussion : title. **task_id**, content

Project Documents : title, **task_id**, etc

The requirement is, when an item in the "Tasks" list is open, in DispForm.aspx page, all the items in "Discussion" and "Documents" which has the same **task_id** should be displayed.

Can someone point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow below steps:

- Add list view web part of the Discussion board on that task DispForm.aspx page.
- Then add **Query String (URL) Filter** from Filters folder.
- Use the ID parameter of the task from the url of the task display form into filter web part for list view web part filtration.

Same approach you can use for Document library list view web part.

Upper mentioned approach is **OOTB** way.

Else you can create **custom web part** to show filtered data for discussion board and document library and can add that custom web part on that task DispForm.aspx page.

Comment: I still do have a problem. In the DispForm.aspx page query string parameter I get is "ID". But it doesn't contain the value for "task_id".

Comment: You need to use item Id for the filtration. As in displayform.aspx url, it will contain only id of the list item. So you need to use that id for the filtration.

Comment: Yeah. I need to add "ID" column to "Discussion" and "Project Documents" as a look up?

Comment: Yes. Please add ID column. Use that for filtration.

Comment: Just did it for "Project Documents" library. And it works fine. Thanks a lot

Comment: My pleasure to help you.